# Check if the data exist in firebase in c#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to add person information, which contains an ID.

When I insert it everything works fine.

When trying to add another person with the same ID, it got updated.

How can I check if already exists?

```
person per = new person()
{
    Name = fullNameTbox.Text,
    ID = idTbox.Text
};
var setter = client.Set("Person/"+idTbox.Text,per);
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions?

Comment: Does not seem like a transaction issue but more like a requirement for unique constraint on ID (OP mentioned 2 users with same ID). Think OP expected an error when adding user 2 with same ID, and he's not knowing how to implement that with FireBase.